# How to handle Firestore deletes after 5 minutes from logged in?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

In my app, I allow only authenticated users to write data to Firestore. I have also implemented an option to revoke access, which requires 2 steps:

```
1. Delete user data from Firstore
2. Delete FirebaseUser object.
```

There are two situations.

- I revoke the access **within** 5 minutes, which means that the user is deleted from Firestore as well as from Firebase Authentication.
- I revoke the access **after** 5 minutes, which means that the user is deleted from Firestore, but not from Firebase Authentication, as it throws a FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException. If I change the order, and I try to delete the FirebaseUser object first, then within 5 minutes, the user is deleted from Firebase Authentication, but not from Firestore, because the delete operation is rejected by the rules due to unauthenticated user.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**Trigger a function on user deletion**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion) to delete the user's data(document) from Firestore after they have been deleted from Firebase Authentication. This will ensure that the user's data is deleted even if they have not signed in within 5 minutes :

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

admin.initializeApp(); // Admin SDK initialization
const db = admin.firestore();

// * Triggered on User Deletion
export const onUserDelete = functions.auth
  .user()
  .onDelete(async (user, context) => {
    console.log(user);
    const docRef = db.collection("users").doc(user.uid);
    await docRef.delete(); // delete user Data from DB on user deletion
    console.log("user Data has been Deleted");
  });
```

As this function will execute in the Trusted Environment so it bypasses the security rules which you can check here [Get started with Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) :

> **Note** : The server client libraries bypass all Cloud Firestore Security Rules and instead authenticate through Google Application Default Credentials. If you are using the server client libraries or the REST or RPC APIs, make sure to set up Identity and Access Management (IAM) for Cloud Firestore.

If you think that this is bulky then you can also use [**Delete User Data**](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/delete-user-data) firebase Extension which is already a tried and tested solution for your application. It automatically deletes all the user data from all firebase Services like realtime-database, Firestore and Firebase Storage when the user gets deleted.

References : [**Firebase Authentication triggers**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events) , [**Delete User Data Extension**](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/delete-user-data)